# {PHP} Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context (Joomla)

Tags: php, joomla

i don't really know php and have hit a brick wall.

The problem is that my site is showing the following error...

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /hermes/web07/b2350/pow.thefoodie/htdocs/index.php on line 11
```

This is the begining of my index.php file...

```
<?php 
/*
  Joomla templates by Joomladesigns.co.uk
 */

// no direct access
 define( 'YOURBASEPATH', dirname(__FILE__) );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
#main_body ul li { behavior: url(<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/iepngfix.htc) }
</style>
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/pngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/fx_styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/accordion.js"></script>

<?php

 // *************************************************
 //
 // Template Parameters
 //
 // *************************************************

 $h1         = $this->params->get("logo");
 $linked_h1    = ($this->params->get("logoLinked", 1)  == 0)?"false":"true";
 $h1_title    = $this->params->get("logoTitle"); 
 $h2_motto  = $this->params->get("logoMotto");

 // Please do NOT change this unless you know what you doing.

 $template_path = $this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template; // template path

 $default_font = "default";


 // **************************************************

?>

</head>
```

Any help would be great as i am completely lost.

Comment: haha.. sorry, bb code doesn't work ;) good try though!

Comment: I'm not really sure what i'm doing, i have no php knowledge really and don't understand it, i will try what you guys suggested. Also what is the code to put around code when posting?

Thnaks guys and i will let you know how i go

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. Looks like it's choking on this bit:

```
<?php echo $this->language; ?>
```

`$this` is only meant to be used inside class methods. Try to find out where "language" is actually defined. You can try replacing `$this->language` with just `$language` but I don't know how your stuff is set up.

**Edit:** Actually, it doesn't look like you have any `include` statements at all prior to that... so *nothing* should be defined. Unless something else is including your `index.php` file, but that's a bit unusual for the index to be included.

If you copied that Joomla template from somewhere, you probably put it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can only use `$this` inside of a class. Outside of a class, `$this` shouldn't exist. It basically references the current class object that you're working inside of. To get this working properly, you need to define a variable as a new class and then reference everything through that variable, such as:

```
$myvar = new MyClass();
$h1 = $myvar->params->get("logo");
```

If that's the kind of thing you're doing.